# Multiple Canvas' next to each other

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, panel

I am making an emulator for a seven segment display calculator with up to 10 digits.
I have the logic down where I have an array of size 10 of objects. These objects take in a number and "turn on" the segments necessary to display the correct number on the canvas. I 
am trying to have 10 separate canvas' next to each other and have a draw function that draws
the correct number in each digit based on what segments are "turned on". Anyways, I can figure 
that part out. The part I can't seem to figure out is how to get 10 separate canvas' next to each other on a single JFrame. I have tried using 10 panels, but the formatting is not working and I'm having issues. Any suggestions on how to make this?

Comment: `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout` may be even `FlowLayout`

Comment: But you recommend still using panels? I am trying to make it look
sort of like this. 
 __   __   __   __   __   __   __   __   __   __
|  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |
|__| |__| |__| |__| |__| |__| |__| |__| |__| |__|

Comment: that came out terrible, but I hope you see at the end what i was trying to do

Comment: May you need to tell us what "canvas" is then

Comment: I guess my real issue is I don't know. I was referring to a Canvas-like object similar to that of javascripts canvas object but in java. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Java has a `Canvas` component, but I wouldn't recommend using it.  You  "could" paint the segments, but personally I might try and set up a series of panels that can act as a single digit and layout them out

Comment: What you suggest is exactly what I am trying to do. Each panel represents an index of the array. So 10 panels for 10 digits. I can already parse the input and fill the array accordingly. Each panel would draw the individual digit based on what segments were turned on, representing that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really basic example of 7 segment display set up using nothing more then custom `JPanel`s...

[image: Segment]

Each element in the display is just a `JPanel` with some additional "properties", which are then laid out on another `JPanel` which acts as the primary display.  You can effect which segements are turned on and off through the use of a `boolean` array, where position;

- 0 is the top
- 1 & 2 are the left and right, top half
- 3 is the middle
- 4 * 5 are the left and right, bottom half
- 6 is the bottom

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TestSegmentDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSegmentDisplay();
    }

    private SegmentDisplay segmentDisplay;
    private int count = 0;

    public TestSegmentDisplay() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                segmentDisplay = new SegmentDisplay();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(segmentDisplay);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        setSegmentValue(segmentDisplay, count);
                        count++;
                        if (count > 9) {
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();

            }
        });
    }

    public static void setSegmentValue(SegmentDisplay display, int value) {

        boolean[] states = new boolean[]{
            false,
            false, false,
            false,
            false, false,
            false
        };
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    true, true,
                    false,
                    true, true,
                    true};
                break;
            case 1:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    false,
                    false, true,
                    false,
                    false, true,
                    false};
                break;
            case 2:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    true,
                    true, false,
                    true};
                break;
            case 3:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    true};
                break;
            case 4:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    false,
                    true, true,
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    false};
                break;
            case 5:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    true, false,
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    true};
                break;
            case 6:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    true, false,
                    true,
                    true, true,
                    true};
                break;
            case 7:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    false,
                    false, true,
                    false};
                break;
            case 8:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    true, true,
                    true,
                    true, true,
                    true};
                break;
            case 9:
                states = new boolean[]{
                    true,
                    true, true,
                    true,
                    false, true,
                    true};
                break;
        }

        display.setSegments(states);

    }

    public static class SegmentDisplay extends JPanel {

        private Segement[] segemnts;

        public SegmentDisplay() {
            segemnts = new Segement[7];
            segemnts[0] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.HORIZONTAL);
            segemnts[1] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.VERTICAL);
            segemnts[2] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.VERTICAL);
            segemnts[3] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.HORIZONTAL);
            segemnts[4] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.VERTICAL);
            segemnts[5] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.VERTICAL);
            segemnts[6] = new Segement(Segement.Direction.HORIZONTAL);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(segemnts[0], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(segemnts[1], gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(segemnts[2], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segemnts[3], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segemnts[4], gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(segemnts[5], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segemnts[6], gbc);
        }

        public void setSegments(boolean[] states) {

            if (states != null && states.length > 0 && states.length == segemnts.length) {

                for (int index = 0; index < segemnts.length; index++) {
                    segemnts[index].setOn(states[index]);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public static class Segement extends JPanel {

        public enum Direction {

            VERTICAL,
            HORIZONTAL;
        }

        public static final int SMALL_SIZE = 10;
        public static final int LARGE_SIZE = SMALL_SIZE * 4;

        protected static final Color OUT_LINE = new Color(128, 0, 0);
        protected static final Color ON_COLOR = Color.RED;
        protected static final Color OFF_COLOR = new Color(64, 0, 0);

        private final Direction direction;
        private boolean on;

        public Segement(Direction direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
            setBorder(new LineBorder(OUT_LINE));
            setOn(true);
            setOn(false);
        }

        public void setOn(boolean value) {
            if (on != value) {
                on = value;
                if (on) {
                    setBackground(ON_COLOR);
                } else {
                    setBackground(OFF_COLOR);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isOn() {
            return on;
        }

        public Direction getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return getDirection() == Direction.VERTICAL ? new Dimension(SMALL_SIZE, LARGE_SIZE) : new Dimension(LARGE_SIZE, SMALL_SIZE);
        }

    }

}
```

There's probably a really clever way to set up the `switch` statement, but I can't really be bothered right now...

What I would then do, is add each `SegmentDisplay` to a `JPanel` using something like `GridBagLayout` or `FlowLayout`...